# Configuring fiddler to listen with visual studio and seperate WCF client/host projects

Tags: visual-studio, fiddler

I have a 2 projects in VS2012. One is a wcf library project. The second project is a simple asp.net site that accesses the wcf service.

How do I configure Fiddler in this environment to capture the wcf traffic back and forth? 
The web page is hosted in IIS Express `http://localhost:50348/test.aspx`
The WCF file is hosted in the WCF Service Host at `http://localhost/8733`
I am using Fiddler 2.4.4.5

Comment: Is the problem that you're not seeing the traffic, or something else? Did you start Fiddler before Visual Studio? Did you follow the steps at http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler has a filters option in which you can specify the name of your computer.
Here's the steps:

1. Make sure you have the latest version of fiddler
2. Click on the "Filters" tab (in the same line of Inspectors).
3. Click on "Use Filters"
4. In the text area enter the name of your computer.
5. Left click on the request area (so it will be saved).

If everything went well, fiddler has a green arrow on the Filters tab.
Just browse to the website using your machine name so instead of:

```
http://localhost/MySite
```

Go to

```
http://my-machine-name/MySite
```

Comment: That gives me an error "No connection could be made because the trarget machine actively refused it"

Comment: try mndv0006:50348/test.aspx

Comment: actually http: //mndv0006:50348/test.aspx gives me a webpage can not be found.

Comment: is there a firewall ? if so then you may have to open the port 50348, can you see results in a web browser when you type http: //mndv0006:50348/test.aspx –

Comment: The web page is able to access the WCF service so I don't think there is a firewall issue. And the firewall rule that shows the Fiddler proxy is not blocking any ports.  FYI both the WCF host and the web page are on the same dev machine.

Comment: strange well try this http://localhost.:50348/test.aspx, notice the dot after localhost (remove all filters), you should be able to see traffic logged